# How to rearrange gridview children when visibility is set to gone?

Tags: android, gridview

I am hiding a child from a gridview by setting its visibility to `View.GONE`. The problem is that even thought I set it to GONE, it becomes invisible but remais still a gap where it was located.

Is it possible to rearrange the gridview, so that the hidden elements don't occupy any space in the layout?

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+activity_queues/gv_queue1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="200dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="none"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>
```

Comment: In the case of `GridView`, even though it is invisible, it still takes up a "cell" of the grid. So, even though the element itself is taking up no space, the parent cell is still taking that space. You may have to remove that cell entirely (save it, perhaps, for later reuse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a single item from your GridView, you have to remove it from the Adapter or the GridView's data source. Since, as you discovered, changing the visibility of a cell won't rearrange your layout, it will just show a blank cell for that item.

Comment: I guess there's no other way. Thank you. I will mark your answer as the correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this issue myself. Weirdly enough, the documentation presents this exact scenario but, after experimenting, it doesn't work:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

It states:

*"For layout purposes, GridLayout treats views whose visibility status is GONE, as having zero width and height. This is subtly different from the policy of ignoring views that are marked as GONE outright. If, for example, a gone-marked view was alone in a column, that column would itself collapse to zero width if and only if no gravity was defined on the view. If gravity was defined, then the gone-marked view has no effect on the layout and the container should be laid out as if the view had never been added to it. GONE views are taken to have zero weight during excess space distribution.
These statements apply equally to rows as well as columns, and to groups of rows or columns."*

Did anyone find a better solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

you can call this method after changing the visibility of views:

```
private void rearrangeVisibleViewsInGridLayout() {
    int childCount=binding.gridLayout.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = binding.gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if(child==null) continue;
        if(child.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
            binding.gridLayout.removeViewAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

GONE should remove it completely and according to the documentation and my experience it no longer takes any space.  So, if it is, then it is probably due to padding or margins from the elements above and below the GridView?

Comment: Sometimes it is best to test your answers first. Create a GridView, use the OnItemClickListener to set every clicked item's visibility to GONE, and you'll see that problem is not the padding or margins.

Comment: Just did and I see no change to my UI with or without a GridView with visibility set to Gone *shrug*

Comment: Are you setting the whole GridView to GONE? The author was asking about a single child _inside_ the grid.